# video-js add simple stop button

Tags: html5-video, video.js

video-js has the default toggle-pause-play button, which works fine. for a specific use, i want to a button next to it that pauses, rewinds, show the poster image and the big play button. in other words, a stop button :-)

it should be a simple plugin, but i cant find the right examples .. it would probably start with

```
videojs.plugin('stopbutton', function(options) {

    var StopButton = videojs.Button.extend({ ....
```

Can anyone point me to the simplest example of adding a button ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711512/how-to-add-new-componentsbuttons-onto-video-js) for a partial answer to your question.

If you decide to build your own "stop" button on top of the videojs interface then the sequence would be something like (API ref [here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api/vjs.Player.md)):

```
myPlayer.pause();
myPlayer.currentTime(0);
myPlayer.posterImage.show(); // as per OP plans
myPlayer.bigPlayButton.show(); // as per OP plans
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. There is a basic intro about writing plugins here https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/plugins.md . in the latest version, the complete set of commands for what i want is  `this.pause(); this.currentTime(0); this.posterImage.show(); this.bigPlayButton.show();`

Comment: Did not know about the this.posterImage.show() - convenient indeed