# HTML5 Video.js plays video too fast

Tags: html, video, video.js

I'm using video.js to embed videos with HTML5 and the video simply plays too fast. I press the play button and I can tell it's at least 1.5x the proper speed.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Sorry! No code. Here you go. By the way, it's copied from videojs.com itself.

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
    preload="auto" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://foo.bar/wp-content/uploads/date/video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

No webm video for now, I'll work on converting the mp4 to that later.

Also, I'm using this in WP; the admin posts videos that we uploads. No video width, height, poster, or id defined.

Comment: what type of video are you trying to play? What OS are you playing them on windows , linux? Which browswer?

Comment: @tsukimi Testing a short mp4 video (30sec long) in Safari on a Mac with Lion. It's just a dummy video I recorded.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027707/how-to-change-the-playing-speed-of-videos-in-html5

Comment: @Larry Battle That actually helps a lot, but I want to know the cause...anyone know?

Comment: Does it work in Chrome for example is the issue just with safari?

Comment: I don't know, is there a place I can test 'in other browsers' so to speak without downloading them?

Comment: @apparatix Google: `test website with different browsers online`. But I think it's best if you download a portable version of the browsers to test.

Comment: Can we see your video online somewhere? Nothing in Video.js would change the playback speed. It'd be something in the file and how the browser plays it back, or maybe some other javascript in the page changing the speed, but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your video is not properly encoded to be compatible with web browsers.

- How did you get the video file in the first place
- Where does it work
- How did you preprocess it for web