# HTML5 Video - Give User Options for Playback Speed

Tags: html, performance, video, playback

I was wondering if there was a way to give a visitor the option to speed up or slow down HTML5 video? Here's how I'm embedding the videos:

```
<center><video class="video" width="1024" height="576" src="Videos/' . $_GET["video"] . '" controls autoplay>If you\'re reading this, your browser sucks. Upgrade your browser to watch this video.</video><center>
```

Is there some way that I could incorporate some controls for the user so that he/she can control the playback speed? e.g. buttons to speed/slow up/down (respectively) the video by X amount?

EDIT:

I've found [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-video-speed-control/ejdipbccipeloijefbkiakckfhdbgocg?hl=en) plugin ([github link](https://github.com/benedictchen/google-chrome-html5video-controls)), and I was wondering if there was a way of incorporating this, or something similar, directly into the website so that the user would not have to install the extension. The reason that this plugin is actually pretty good, is that it allows for the playback speed to be altered whilst the video is playing.

Comment: For speed-control via keyboard keys try https://stackoverflow.com/a/67440385

Comment: For speed-control via just keyboard keys, try https://stackoverflow.com/a/67440385

Answer (score 3):

In order to control the playback rate, you can using playbackRate property. Please look at this question which answers your question  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3027957/1020337)

Comment: Not very elegant, is it?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The asker is trying to incorporate playback *controls* for the user, not just set the playback speed.

Answer (score 0):

For speed-control via keyboard keys try stackoverflow.com/a/67440385

(Someone please delete duplicate comments above, and move THIS comment to answer #1, where "add a comment" was ACTUALLY clicked - TY -- Sorry, cannot even flag this issue.)

Comment: Mouse over on your comment so that you will able to see delete option. Also remove unwanted text from your answer. Provide links in hyperlink format.