# Is there a way to change Jquery plugin options with a click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jplayer

I am using the [Jplayer](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-playbackRate) query plugin as an audio player on mysite. While I manage to set the options of the plugin through this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            title: MediaTitle,
            mp3: MediaURL
        });
    },
    remainingDuration: true,
    defaultPlaybackRate: 1,  /* <-- I'd like to change the playback rate 
                                    when I click a button */
    toggleDuration: true
});
});
```

my goal is to assign a button to control the playback rate so when for example I press "speed" button the deafultPlaybackRate would go from 1 to 1.5 for example.

I'm thinking approaching this is by using the .click mouse event.

For example:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $( ".speeder" ).click(function() {
       /*make the defaultPlaybackRate go from 1 to 1.5 */
    });
   </script>
```

Am I on the right path? is it even possible to change global jquery plugin settings through events like a mouse click on a button?

Comment: `$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("options",{defaultPlaybackRate : 1.5});` If plugin follows jQuery plugins code standards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the playing speed of videos in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027707/how-to-change-the-playing-speed-of-videos-in-html5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [documentation here](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $( ".speeder" ).click(function() {
       $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("option","playbackRate", "1.5"); // or
       //$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("option",{playbackRate : 1.5});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this code seems about right but it doesn't work for me unfortunately :(

Thank you for your answer though

Comment: @vinayaki
http://jsfiddle.net/FLVR/XLNCY/18402/
Hopefully this is understandable...
I am trying to assign to assign the speed buttons (.button1, .button125, .button15) to control the defaultPlaybackRate parameter accordingly

Comment: Well code is running correctly, you can check the log. http://jsfiddle.net/pxocLg68/

Comment: according to the log it running fine but unfortunately the actual speed of the track isn't changing

Comment: Thats `defaultPlaybackRate` its there when you dont change, I think you need to revisit API docs to find right method to change playback rate maybe
 `$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("option","playbackRate", "1.5");`