# How to change speed on embedded YouTube video

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I embedded a YouTube video in a web site and want to change the speed of this video.
I know that it is possible to change speed in HTML5 videos (cf [How to change the playing speed of videos in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027707/how-to-change-the-playing-speed-of-videos-in-html5)). The problem is that YouTube videos are embedded as an iframe.

I found this code jsfiddle.net/jpreynat/e11oy0eu/ but it only works on desktops and not with mobile devices.

Is there a possibility to change the YouTube video speed on every device?

Comment: I tried code from http://jsfiddle.net/jpreynat/e11oy0eu/
But the Youtube player API only works for desktops.

Additionaly I tried to get the video player from the Youtube iframe and to change the speed via the player properties. This was not possible due to cross-site-scripting:

'<iframe id="myf" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE"></iframe>
  
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var frame = document.getElementById("myf");
    var fdoc = frame.contentDocument;

    fdoc.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].playbackRate = 2;
</script>'

Answer (score 6):

Try using postMessage on iframe to pass setPlaybackRate command with rate in argument

```
var playbackRate = 2;
var data = {event: 'command', func: 'setPlaybackRate', args: [playbackRate, true]};
var message = JSON.stringify(data);
$('#iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');
```