# Is there a way to change the frame rate of a video playing in html5?

Tags: html

I have a video playing at 60 fps in html5 and I would like to know if there is a way to add the option for it to be changed e.g. to 30fps at anytime in the browser. And if so how could you.

Thanks for your time

Comment: @Quentin Why did you mark this as a duplicate? Video playback speed and frame rate are two totally different things. Changing a video from 60 frames per **second** to 30 frames per second will still play the video at the same speed. The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027707/how-to-change-the-playing-speed-of-videos-in-html5) you reference asks for a way to change the playback speed.

Comment: I've been searching for a solution to this as well but the spec doesn't seem to support changing frame rates. Hopefully someone could prove me wrong. Depending on you situation you could do one of two things though. You could have two versions of the video and [dynamically change the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235145/changing-source-on-html5-video-tag). A much nastier way would be to sort of emulate the frame rate by manually seeking the video in an interval but this will likely have a delay and not perform well.