# How to set playback speed of html5 video/audio if the video/audio element is not present in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

[How to change the playing speed of videos in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027707/how-to-change-the-playing-speed-of-videos-in-html5) depicts a way of setting the playback speed of a html5 audio/video element, but the answers given in that question rely on the actual video/audio tag being present in the dom. The website - SoundCloud - in particular does not put the audio player in the DOM anywhere, but it still does use it internally. Since document.queryselector will not work, how can I set the playback rate?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to actually insert the audio tag into the DOM.

quick example here:

```
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', event => {
    const audio = document.createElement('audio')
  audio.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
  audio.play()
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v4ma95L2/

Comment: is there a way of finding it again, if it isn't part of the DOM though?

Comment: You have to save a reference for later usage I guess.